# how to make five * five matrix determinant in C language?

Tags: c

I want to know how to make 5*5 matrix determinant.
I already made from 1*1 matrix determinant to 4*4 matrix determinant but i don't know how to make 5*5 matrix determinant by using C language.
Thank you for helping me.

Comment: "*I already made*". Please show the code you have tried and explain what specific difficulty prevents you from extending that for your desired result.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a five element times 5 element matrix:

```
 int TheMatrix[5][5] = {{1,2,3,4,6},
                {6,1,5,3,8},
                {2,6,4,9,9},
                {1,3,8,3,4},
                {5,7,8,2,5}};
```

The matrix here is two dimesional.